# Using find command in bash script

Tags: bash, find, command

I just start to use bash script and i need to use find command with more than one file type.

```
list=$(find /home/user/Desktop -name '*.pdf')
```

this code work for pdf type but i want to search more than one file type like .txt or .bmp together.Have you any idea ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Welcome to bash. It's an old, dark and mysterious thing, capable of great magic.  :-)

The option you're asking about is for the `find` command though, not for bash.  From your command line, you can `man find` to see the options.

The one you're looking for is `-o` for "or":

```
  list="$(find /home/user/Desktop -name '*.bmp' -o -name '*.txt')"
```

That said ... ***Don't do this.***  Storage like this may work for simple filenames, but as soon as you have to deal with special characters, like spaces and newlines, all bets are off. See [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for details.

```
$ touch 'one.txt' 'two three.txt' 'foo.bmp'
$ list="$(find . -name \*.txt -o -name \*.bmp -type f)"
$ for file in $list; do if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then echo "MISSING: $file"; fi; done
MISSING: ./two
MISSING: three.txt
```

Pathname expansion (globbing) provides a much better/safer way to keep track of files. Then you can also use bash arrays:

```
$ a=( *.txt *.bmp )
$ declare -p a
declare -a a=([0]="one.txt" [1]="two three.txt" [2]="foo.bmp")
$ for file in "${a[@]}"; do ls -l "$file"; done
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  staff  0 24 May 16:27 one.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  staff  0 24 May 16:27 two three.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  staff  0 24 May 16:27 foo.bmp
```

The [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) has lots of other excellent tips about programming in bash.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to loop over what you "find", you should use this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/343727/filenames-with-spaces-breaking-for-loop-find-command

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
list=$(find /home/user/Desktop -name '*.pdf' -o -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.bmp')
```

Besides, you might want to use `-iname` instead of `-name` to catch files with ".PDF" (upper-case) extension as well.

Comment: To cope with filenames with spaces you'll need to use quotes for the `$list` variable later, as in `for i in "$list"; do echo $i; done`. Without double quotes your script will consider each "filename like this.jpg" as three files: "filename", "like" and "this.jpg".