# Finding filenames with specific string in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to write a bash script to do a batch processing of some fMRI data. My problem is that I am not able to get the filenames that match a specific pattern within the directory of interest.

My scripts looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

inputpath="/Volumes/External_HD/Experiments/MRI_Data"
outputpath="/Volumes/External_HD/Experiments/MRI_Data_output"

anatomical_scans=$find `$inputpath` -name *mprage

# RUN BET
bet $anatomical_scans $outputpath

echo 'Finished!!!'
```

The only output that I get is the following error message

```
-name: command not found
```

I am definetely not familiar with shell scripting so I am sorry if the question may sound trivial. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Antonio

EDIT:: SOLVED

Exploring the suggestions I found the correct way to make it running with no errors

```
anatomical_scans=$(find $input_path -name "*mprage*")
```

Thanks

Comment: You miss some ''.. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509226/using-find-command-in-bash-script

Comment: Learn to use http://shellcheck.net **before** you post your code here ;-) . When you use shellcheck, you need to include a proper "she-bang" line as the first line, usually `#!/bin/bash` . AND avoid the top 10 shell script beginner mistakes by reading https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info multiple times. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

try changing the line

`anatomical_scans=$find`$inputpath`-name *mprage`

to

```
anatomical_scans=$(find "${inputpath}" -name "*mprage")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

inputpath="/Volumes/External_HD/Experiments/MRI_Data"
outputpath="/Volumes/External_HD/Experiments/MRI_Data_output"

function anatomical_scans {
    find $inputpath -name "*mprage"
}

# RUN BET
bet anatomical_scans $outputpath

echo "Finished!!!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try as below, hope it can help.

```
#!/bin/bash

inputpath="/Volumes/External_HD/Experiments/MRI_Data"
outputpath="/Volumes/External_HD/Experiments/MRI_Data_output"

anatomical_scans=`find $inputpath -name '*mprage'`

# RUN BET
bet $anatomical_scans $outputpath

echo 'Finished!!!'
```

Comment: Although it works, the syntax `var=$(command)` is preferred since it solves quoting issues, and others as described here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082